# Uboot function pci_hose_read_config_word() define?

Tags: c, u-boot, pci, pci-e, pci-bus

Currently i am study uboot pci init process

There has a function call `pci_hose_read_config_word()` in pci bus scan.

[Here is Source Code](https://github.com/trini/u-boot/blob/master/drivers/pci/pci.c#L365)

But i search all sourcecode in uboot, why i can not find the function implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function definition is in [`pci_compat.c`, line 26](https://github.com/trini/u-boot/blob/d7482ca4265fbe4065b28ace998636f78406ed95/drivers/pci/pci_compat.c#L26):

> ```
> PCI_HOSE_OP(read, word, 16, u16 *)
> ```

You didn't find it because it's hidden behind a macro (`PCI_HOSE_OP`) that assembles the function name from parts and also supplies the body.